# Mysql command-line login changes my host

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem trying to connect to a mysql database server located at 192.168.1.152 using this;

```
In our DNS server;
mysql.domain.local = 192.168.1.152
kyle.domain.local = 192.168.1.153

Doing this command from the 192.168.1.153 system
mysql -h 192.168.1.152 -D mydb -u dbuser -p******
mysql -h mysql.domain.local -D mydb -u dbuser -p******
```

When I run these commands, both always returns the following;

```
Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'kyle.domain.local' (using password: YES)
```

Why does this keep doing this? I can ping each host listed above and get the associated IP for them, but yet the mysql command still does this. What is going on?

Comment: Well, you could be using the wrong password.

Comment: Okay...this just got insane! I just was able to successfully login, but the weirdest part is that what allowed it to work was to remove the password from the command-line -p argument and supply it at the prompt. All I did was copy it as I had it typed and then pasted it at the prompt. What the HELL is going on with that?!

Answer (score 0):

If your password contains special character (such as '!') then the unix shell may be interpreting that.

You can try enclosing the password in single quotes, to prevent the shell from interpreting it.

```
mysql -h mysql.domain.local -D mydb -u dbuser -p'******'
                                                ^      ^
```

---

Also, MySQL is doing a reverse lookup of the IP address, and resolving that to a host name.

The Access Denied is because MySQL isn't finding a matching host/user/password entry (row in the mysql.user table).

It's possible to use IP addresses rather than hostnames, but then an IP address rather than a hostname has to be in the host column of the mysql.user, mysql.db et al. tables.

To avoid reverse lookups of hostnames from IP addresses, add `skip-name-resolve` under the [mysqld] section of my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

Note that with this option, MySQL will ignore all entries in mysql.user that have a hostname; all users will need to be defined with an IP address.  The '%' as a wildcard match for all hostnames and IP addresses will still work.)